# flutter file_picker is not showing gallery images for selection

Tags: flutter

I need to show user all the files stored in local storage(pdf, doc, images etc). I am using file_picker as such:

```
  void handleOnTap(BuildContext context) async {
    final currentContext = context;

    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.any,
    );
    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
      if (currentContext.mounted) {
        VaultRepository.of(currentContext).addItem(file).then((value) {
          showSuccessSnackBar(currentContext, "File uploaded successfully");
        }).catchError((e) {
          showErrorSnackbar(
              currentContext, Utility.getSanitizedErrorMessage(e));
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

But this only shows files but not images. I get images only if I set `type: FileType.media`. But I need to show all files at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code segment,

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  allowMultiple: true,
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx'], // Add extensions of the file types you want to allow
);
```

You should give permission from you'r emulator,

Follow bellow steps,

1.Go to setting on you'r emulator,

2.And now go to apps.

3.And find Gallery.

4.Go into the Gallery app info.

5.You can see now Permission,

6.Give access camera and Storage.

Look at bellow images you can get some idea,
[image]

Comment: permissions are already given. As mentioned in my post, I get the camera images if I set `type = FileType.media` but I need images and files all at once.

Comment: I update answer look at new update import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  allowMultiple: true,
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx'], // Add extensions of the file types you want to allow
);

Comment: still nothing. I am only getting the documents like pdf, doc,docx but not images on both ios and android. But setting the type to media gives me images and not documents