# file_picker plugin of flutter where file type is any is not working

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to use file_picker plugin of flutter and below code to select file

```html
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        withData: true,
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'docx', 'doc', 'txt'],
        allowMultiple: true,
      );
```

but no matter i use FileType.custom or FileType.any its not working. Always returns null.
but of FileType.image or FileType.media its works fine.
I am using the latest version of file_picker plugin i.e. 6.1.1

Steps i followed:

Downloaded a pdf file from internet. The pdf file url is https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

I have given permission for read and write operation in AndroidManifest.xml i.e.

```html
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then i have below function:

```html
Future<void> handleFilePicker(BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    setState(() {
      isPickingFile = true;
    });

    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      withData: true,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'docx', 'doc', 'txt'],
      allowMultiple: false,
    );
    // Here i am getting the result as null
    if (result != null) {
      File imageFile = File(result.files.single.path!);
      if (imageFile.lengthSync() > 8 * 1024 * 1024) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text(
              FILE_SIZE_TOOBIG,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        );
        return;
      }

      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Text('Uploading...'),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      );
       // Making some server call
    }
  } catch (e, stackTrace) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    postStackTrace(stackTrace.toString());
  }
}
```

Exactly similar but another function i have where i am giving FileType as image

FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
type: FileType.image,
allowMultiple: false,
);

and its working. Only in the case of any or custom its not working.

To test this i am using Samsung M14 5G mobile.

[image]

Comment: Who created the custom files;? Android version of used device?

Comment: FileType.custom is part of library. And android version 13. Samsung device. https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Comment: That is no answer to my question. You want to select custom files. I asked who created the custom files you wanna select now. You might tell file extension(s).

Comment: And if you use any then we still wanna know who created the files on your device that you wanna select with 'any'.

Comment: The file extension is pdf and i downloaded from internet. Its stored in local device which i am trying to select. Even i tried doc file which i downloaded from internet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77549334/20521312 Try using this

Comment: I downloaded... Sorry you should exactly tell how you did that

Comment: Updated the description with steps i am following. Also checked in iPhone, the same code working.